# Is there a root final stop in English?

Tags: grammar, roots

Is there a root final stop in English? I can't seem to find any

Comment: What do you mean by ‘root’? English doesn’t really have ‘roots’ in a generic sense, in the way that some other languages do.

Comment: And where are you getting that from? If you consider _fit_ a root and _-ness_ a suffix, you’d predict _*finness_, but the word is _fitness_.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by 'root final' to prevent this question from being closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example "think" – the root is /θɪŋk/, /k/ is a stop.